# How to replace the deprecated AudioUnitSampleType on iOS (Audio Units)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

I've been studying the Audio Unit Hosting Guide for iOS, and then trying to play around with the sample projects provided. However, all of these projects are using the deprecated AudioUnitSampleType (which seems to be a simple typedef). It might be a rookie question, but how do I go about changing it with something? 
As far as my understanding goes, I should replace it with different types (SInt16 or Float) depending on the target iOS version (of course, I want to target as many as possible). So should I just write a bunch of #ifndef's or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of guessing/ifdef'ing, you should get the kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat property for each audio unit and use the native format for that audio unit under that iOS version.  Most likely 4-byte floats for any recent iOS version on any recent iOS device, as all the recent Apple A? processors can do arithmetic using floats as fast or faster than with SInt16 or SInt32 data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, appreciate it.
So just to be clear -- in order to dynamically configure the right format to be used, I need to declare different structs each of which is designed for the specific type (SInt16 or Float32), and then make the decision depending on what the kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat property I am dealing with. Right?

Comment: Before doing all that work, check whether you have any iOS test devices that don't report using a float stream format.